# Cards are being placed on top of each other angular 10

Tags: angular

I have this problem, I am bringing my lists and my cards without problem but when getting the data my cards are not separated by means of the id of the lists the two data arrive but the data that comes second applies to the first and is placed in the lists and i should separate it by your id here i leave my ts and html code

html

```html
 class="px-4 pb-4" >
    <div (click)="open(board, list, card)" 
         *ngFor="let card of customersy;  index as indexOfelement;"
         class="scrumboard-card card w-full cursor-pointer overflow-hidden"
    >
    <!--   
      <div *ngIf="card.cover" class="w-full h-40 overflow-hidden">
         <img [src]="card.cover.path" class="object-cover w-full h-full">
      </div> -->
  
    <div class="p-4" >
       <div class="mb-2" fxLayout="row" fxLayoutGap="8px">
          <div
             [ngClass]="{
              'bg-amber': card.label_color === 'High Priority', 
              'bg-red': card.label_color === 'Blocked', 
              'bg-green': card.label_color === 'Approved' , 
              'bg-cyan': card.label_color === 'Ready', 
              'bg-purple': card.label_color === 'Deployed'}"
              class="label "
              fxFlex >
           </div>
        </div> 
        <p class="body-2 m-0 select-none" >{{  card.name  }}</p>
```

ts

```js
ngOnInit(){

  this.route.paramMap.pipe(map((param: ParamMap) => 
          {
                    // @ts-ignore
                    return param.params.id;
          }))
         .subscribe(prodId => {
             this.id = prodId;
             console.log("Titulo de Proyecto", prodId)
             this.API.getNombreProyecto(this.id).subscribe(prod => {
             this.project = prod;
         });         
    }); 
           
   this.API.getListas(this.id)
     .subscribe((data: Customer[]) => {
          this.customersx = data;
          console.log('Obtener Listas:::', this.customersx);
          data.forEach((element , i) => {
          this.API.getCards(element.id )
              .subscribe((data2: any) => {
                    this.customersy = data2;
                    console.log("Data 2", data2)
               });  
      });            
  });
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The variable customersy should be an array but you are reassigning it in for loop. That is why it takes the latest value.

```
this.API.getListas(this.id)
 .subscribe((data: Customer[]) => {
      this.customersx = data;
      console.log('Obtener Listas:::', this.customersx);
      data.forEach((element , i) => {
      this.API.getCards(element.id )
          .subscribe((data2: any) => {
                this.customersy.push(data2); // push to array
                console.log("Data 2", data2)
           });  
  });
```